# How to set default selected option in combobox headless-ui?

Tags: reactjs, headless-ui

I want the first option to be selected by default in dropdown. I tried `combobox` `defaultValue` property but didn't work. How can i do this?

Combobox Component

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { CheckIcon, ChevronUpDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid'
import { Combobox } from '@headlessui/react'

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

export default function FormCombobox({
  comboboxData,
  label,
  questionRange,
  setQuestionRange,
}) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  let items = comboboxData.map((item) => ({
    id: item.content_object.nanoid,
    name: item.content_object.name,
    multiplier: item.multiplier,
  }))

  const filteredItems =
    query === ''
      ? items
      : items.filter((item) => {
          return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
        })

  return (
    <Combobox
      as="div"
      value={questionRange}
      onChange={setQuestionRange}
      className="my-5"
    >
      <Combobox.Label className="block text-left font-bold text-gray-700">
        {label}
      </Combobox.Label>
      <div className="relative mt-1">
        <Combobox.Input
          className="w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-10 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
          onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
          displayValue={(item) => item?.name}
        />
        <Combobox.Button className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center rounded-r-md px-2 focus:outline-none">
          <ChevronUpDownIcon
            className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
            aria-hidden="true"
          />
        </Combobox.Button>

        {filteredItems.length > 0 && (
          <Combobox.Options className="absolute z-10 mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
            {filteredItems.map((item) => (
              <Combobox.Option
                key={item.id}
                value={item}
                className={({ active }) =>
                  classNames(
                    'relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9',
                    active ? 'bg-indigo-600 text-white' : 'text-gray-900'
                  )
                }
              >
                {({ active, selected }) => (
                  <>
                    <span
                      className={classNames(
                        'block truncate',
                        selected && 'font-semibold'
                      )}
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </span>

                    {selected && (
                      <span
                        className={classNames(
                          'absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4',
                          active ? 'text-white' : 'text-indigo-600'
                        )}
                      >
                        <CheckIcon className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </>
                )}
              </Combobox.Option>
            ))}
          </Combobox.Options>
        )}
      </div>
    </Combobox>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

initialize the state of `questionRange`  when declaring it .

```
const [questionRange, setQuestionRange] = useState(items[0])
```

Comment: if it didn't work move `let items = comboboxData.map((item) => ({
    id: item.content_object.nanoid,
    name: item.content_object.name,
    multiplier: item.multiplier,
  }))` to the parent component and pass **items**  in the props instead of **comboboxData*